# What does the Airbus A340 Primary Flight Display look like during startup?

Tags: display, airbus-a340

I'm developing a simulator addon and I'd like to accurately show what the A340 Primary Flight Display (PFD) shows during its startup sequence.

I'm looking for any images, photos, documents or movies that show the display from a cold and dark start until it's fully operative. That might include different states like a boot screen, self test and so on.

I can easily find information on what the PFD looks like once startup is complete, but what is displayed before that point?

Comment: Your question will probably do better if it's clearer. Try removing phrases like "or whatever" and make sure there is a clear question and other relevant details are clear. Good formatting also encourages answers.

Comment: I'm developer of such addon so i need some info from the real world. I'm in contact with pilots of A340, but they cannot provide me such informations so far. A340 cold and dark gives nothing (except simulations) - this is not so easy as it looks. By "whatever" i mean each state, which could be shown, i'm not aware sofar how they are called, so i hope that someone will be able to explain what is what.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Initially, I would like to apologize for the not-so-good quality of the pictures (there were taken into a busy enviroment).

I tried to find some vector photos from the respective manuals but I couldn't, that's why I took them by myself.

I am going to provide you with some information on each photo. It is very synoptic description in order to get the help you need for the development of your stuff, and to cover this question.

In case that you need any further technical information please open another question.

> **1) Immediately after provide the a/c with power.**

[image: PFD after power up]

> **2) After 40s**

[image: PFD After 40s OF POWERUP]

> **3) After approximately 50s and before initialization of the ADIRS (which is taking place at cockpit preparation after the preliminary cockpit preparation checklist.)**

[image: PFD A340 After approximately 50s FROM POWERUP]

> **4) Approximately 15s after the startup of the ADIRS, and during the "IR alignment in progress." (info* on ECAM)**

[image: PFD A340 Approximately 15s after the startup of the ADIRS, and during the "IR alignment in progress.]

> **5) During IR alignment in progress. (Only here the FDs are by default ON when the a/c is powering up, and the red FD symbol on the PFD during alignment is flashing, then manually FDs are switched off.)**

[image: AIRBUS PFD During IR alignment in progress.]

> **6) After IR alignment and before FMGS PERF PAGE preparation, (and FDs still are OFF).**

[image: AIRBUS PFD After IR alignment and before FMGS PERF PAGE preparation, (and FDs still are OFF]

> **7) FDs are ON, FMGS preparation at PERF PAGE not completed yet, and ENGINES are OFF.**

[image: AIRBUS PFD FDs are ON, FMGS preparation at PERF PAGE not completed yet, and ENGINES are OFF.]

> **8) FMGS PERF PAGE data inserted, FDs ON, ENGINES OFF.**

[image: AIRBUS PFD FMGS PERF PAGE data inserted, FDs ON, ENGINES OFF.]

Comment: Welcome! One cannot dream of a better answer.

Comment: Yeah mins, you are right - no better answer. Above material is just amazing, real treasure for me :). Big Thank You Emmanuel!

Comment: My pleasure Robert...